# Logs with unwanted value

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, logging, newrelic

I have been trying to do the logging part in My Springboot appication.
My logs are filled with unwanted stuff

`"\u0006stdout\u0010��������\u0017\u001a�\u00012023-05-20 08:48:38.366 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - REQUEST DATA : GET /dg/public/course]\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000�"`

Just wanted the  `GET /dg/public/course`

How can i achieve that.
This is my logback.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <property name="LOGS" value="/tmp/logs" />

  <appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>
        %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder
      class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  </root>

  <!-- LOG "com.teaching.gradzee*" at TRACE level -->
  <logger name="com.teaching.gradzee" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="DEBUG"/>
<!--  <logger name="org.zalando.logbook" level="TRACE" />-->
</configuration>
```

Using new relic for logging.

Agent is running in ec2, my application is in Docker

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your application is logging and at what log level. Increase the levels from debug and trace to at least info. Those are usually too verbose and show too many details. It depends on spring boot if it will show the actual information that you want. Else you need to add your own logger to the application.